# Why does the .size method not respond with the actual value stored in my counter_cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, counter-cache

I have a `Question` model that `has_many :answers` & `#  answers_count :integer default(0)`

On my `Answer` model, I have:

```
belongs_to :question, counter_cache: true
```

On my `Question#Show` page though, when showing my `Answer#Form` partial, I build an instance of an answer to be included in the form like so:

```
<%= render partial: "answers/form", locals: {answer: @question.answers.build(user: current_user)} %>
```

Right below that, I display the number of answers currently associated with this question. It should NOT include that unpersisted answer I just `built` in the form, yet it does.

This is the value of a `@question`:

```
[3] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fadab5f4d48>>)> question
=> #<Question:0x007fadab7f3478
 id: 51,
 title: "Chile loves Mexico A LOT",
 body: "5.times do\r\n puts \"*\"\r\nend\r\n\r\nputs \"Chile, Chile, Chile!\"\r\nputs \"Whips Mejico 7 - LOVE\"",
 user_id: 1546,
 created_at: Mon, 20 Jun 2016 09:05:09 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Mon, 20 Jun 2016 20:40:23 UTC +00:00,
 test_suite: "",
 expected_results: "",
 language: "ruby",
 comments_count: 1,
 runnable: false,
 answers_count: 0>
```

When I do various calls, I get different results:

```
[4] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fadab5f4d48>>)> question.answers.count
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 51]]
=> 0
```

That gives me the result I want, but it also does a DB-query which I am trying to avoid. The call to `size` seems to hit the cached value but it gives me the wrong value as you can see below.

```
[5] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fadab5f4d48>>)> question.answers.size
=> 1
[6] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fadab5f4d48>>)> question.answers_count
=> 0
```

Shouldn't `.size` just return what is in `answers_count`? Why is it not working like I expect? I can always just use `answers_count`, but I feel like there may be a bigger problem here that I would love to get to the bottom of.

Comment: `.size` giving you count from the loaded records in the memory. And it is `1` because in memory you have now `1`, as the partial rendering line shows in your question. `.count` will always hit the DB, as the answer is not persisted yet, it gives you `0`. Does it help? Btw, when you have the _cache_ set up, then use `answers_count` always, don't use the other 2 methods as u did.

Comment: @ArupRakshit That's what I am realizing, but the actual documentation from Rails says that `.size` will give you the cached result -- which clearly isn't the case.

Comment: I think by _cahce_, they meant probably the already loaded records in memory. But not about your counter_cache columns really. Point me to that doc link please.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Check it out here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html  (point 4.1.2.3)